# Connect to SQL Server on network from Google

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have tried to connect to a SQL Server from a Google Script on the LAN using this

```
var conn = Jdbc.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://Linden:1433;databaseName=Centaman_Live;user=SSRS1;password=****;");
```

and

```
var conn = Jdbc.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://Linden:1433;Centaman_Live;SSRS1;****;");
```

and

```
var conn = Jdbc.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://Linden:1433;Centaman_Live;'SSRS1';'****';");
```

but have failed - - I reviewed numerous discussions on this site and others but  nothing seems to work.

I can go to the server and sign on to the SQL Server using the same credentials as in the command above. I can connect to `Linden` from other servers using SQL Server or SSRS

Don't have much hair left but what hair I do have I'm pulling out trying to get this to work

Comment: Where is the "Google Script" being executed?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but you can find a full list of valid SQL Server connection strings (and others!) at this [web site](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/).